# Problem with camera while running SVO live

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everybody,

I'm trying to launch the live of SVO, but it gives me immediately this type of error:

```
[ INFO] [1418401675.780991894]: SVO initialized
[ INFO] [1418401675.791371920]: Found parameter: svo/cam_topic, value: /ardrone/front/image_raw
[ INFO] [1418401734.849896333]: RESET
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Frame: provided image has not the same size as the camera model or image is not grayscale
[svo-1] process has died [pid 11270, exit code -6, cmd /home/jacopo/catkin_ws/devel/lib/svo_ros/vo __name:=svo __log:=/home/jacopo/.ros/log/8b460c10-8218-11e4-ba87-001e6480e144/svo-1.log].
log file: /home/jacopo/.ros/log/8b460c10-8218-11e4-ba87-001e6480e144/svo-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

how i could solve it??
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201031/problem-with-camera-while-running-svo-live/) by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the error it looks like you might feed the system color images, but it only is able to process grayscale. Another possibility seems to be that the resolution (image size) stated in your camera_info and your image are not consistent. That would be my first guesses, given the message

```
Frame: provided image has not the same size as the camera model or image is not grayscale
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-01-15**:
how i can convert my image in grayscale??

**Comment by [zhujimson](https://answers.ros.org/users/21605/zhujimson/) on 2016-12-19**:
I got the same question,  can someone tell me how can i fix this problem?

**Comment by [nidamarthy](https://answers.ros.org/users/41575/nidamarthy/) on 2019-05-15**:
you could just run the image_proc node to get the grayscale image or write your own subscriber and publisher to convert the rgb image to grayscale